# StickyHeaderIndices do not work properly in an inverted FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I am still new to react native and am working on a chat app. I am using  element to display the long list of messages and add inverted prop to it, to show the last messages by default. But making my FlatList inverted, disturbed the functionality of stickyHeaderIndices that I am using to display the days of the messages (like they do in WhatsApp). Its been two days, I am stuck on this.

I am also attaching the piece of code for  I am using..

```
<FlatList    
    style={{ flex: 1 }}    
    data={messageList}    
    renderItem={this.renderMessage}    
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}    
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}    
    stickyHeaderIndices={stickyHeaders}   
    inverted   
/>
```

where variable `messageList` is an array of all the messages, inlcuding the headers I wish to display, `this.renderMessage` displays the individual message, `stickyHeaders` is an array with indexes of the headers that are stored in `messageList`.

Comment: Exact self-duplicate of [stickyHeaderIndices does not work properly in an inverted FlatList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63741120/stickyheaderindices-does-not-work-properly-in-an-inverted-flatlist)